# Optimize query with multiple OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, cross-apply, outer-apply

I'm having query with multiple `OUTER APPLY` but all tables have primary keys on joined columns (so clustered indexes are used here) so I don't know how to optimize this query futher. Also it's impossible to use indexed view here because using `ORDER BY` and `TOP` is forbidden for them.

So I'm having

- Table `Fields` with `Id` primary key and big variety of other columns.
- `WeatherHistory` table with complex primary key (`FieldId` and `[Date]`) and a lot of columns,
- `NdviImageHistory` table with `FieldId`, `[Date]`, `[Base64]` columns (complex primary key `FieldId` and `[Date]`) where `[Base64]` stores image base64,
- `NaturalColorImageHistory` table with `FieldId`, `[Date]`, `[Base64]` columns (complex primary key `FieldId` and `[Date]`) where `[Base64]` stores image base64,
- `NdviHistory` table with with `FieldId`, `[Date]`, `MeanNdvi` columns (complex primary key `FieldId` and `[Date]`),
- `FieldSeasonHistory` table with `Field`, `StartDate`, `EndDate` columns (complex primary key `FieldId` and `[Date]`).

My query

```
SELECT Fields.*,
    WeatherHistory.TempSumC AS CurrentTempSumC,
    TempSumF AS CurrentTempSumF,
    PrecipitationSumMm AS CurrentPrecipitationSumMm,
    nih.[Base64] AS CurrentNdviImageBase64,
    ncih.[Base64] AS CurrentNaturalColorImageBase64,
    MeanNdvi AS CurrentMeanNdvi,
    IsOpenSeason
FROM Fields
LEFT JOIN WeatherHistory ON FieldId = Id AND [Date] = CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [Base64]
    FROM NdviImageHistory
    WHERE FieldId = Id
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
) nih
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [Base64]
    FROM NaturalColorImageHistory
    WHERE FieldId = Id
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
) ncih
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 MeanNdvi
    FROM NdviHistory
    WHERE FieldId = Id
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
) nh
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsOpenSeason
    FROM FieldSeasonHistory
    WHERE FieldId = Id
    ORDER BY [StartDate] DESC
) fsh
WHERE UserId = (SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Email = @email) AND IsArchived = 0
```

I haven't created any indexes because I suppose that autogenerated clusted indexes (based on primary keys) should be enough (but I can be wrong). This query is executed about 15 seconds, but I want to reduce query time.

---

**Edit:** Added indexes to `UserId` and `IsArchived` columns of `Fields` table. Query execution plan:

[image]

---

** Edit 2:** Statistics:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(13 row(s) affected)
Table 'FieldSeasonHistory'. Scan count 13, logical reads 26, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'NdviHistory'. Scan count 13, logical reads 26, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'NaturalColorImageHistory'. Scan count 13, logical reads 26, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 604, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'NdviImageHistory'. Scan count 13, logical reads 39, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 68, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'WeatherHistory'. Scan count 0, logical reads 39, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Users'. Scan count 0, logical reads 228, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Fields'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 16 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multicolumn indexes for each of the tables.  The index should be the column in the where, the column in the `order by` and then the column in the `select`.  For instance:

- `NdviImageHistory(FieldId, [Date], [Base64])`
- `NaturalColorImageHistory(FieldId, [Date], [Base64])`
- and so on.

Comment: I need to create separate indexes for every column or single indexes for multiple columns?

Comment: I mean one per each table or one per column?

Comment: Also I can't index `[Base64]` because it's `VARCHAR(MAX)` column.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov . . . Then create indexes with the first two columns.  These are composite indexes -- indexes with multiple columns.

Comment: OK, I get it. For tables `NdviImageHistory` and `NaturalColorImageHistory` there are already clustered indexes because first two columns are composite primary key. Also I assume that the issue is connected with this tables because if I remove them from query, query executes in a second.

Answer (score -1):

Update your query like this.

```
SELECT Fields.*,
    WeatherHistory.TempSumC AS CurrentTempSumC,
    TempSumF AS CurrentTempSumF,
    PrecipitationSumMm AS CurrentPrecipitationSumMm,
    nih.[Base64] AS CurrentNdviImageBase64,
    ncih.[Base64] AS CurrentNaturalColorImageBase64,
    MeanNdvi AS CurrentMeanNdvi,
    IsOpenSeason
FROM Fields
LEFT JOIN WeatherHistory ON FieldId = Id AND [Date] = CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(NdviImageHistory.ID) MAX_ID
    FROM NdviImageHistory
    WHERE FieldId = Id

) nih_ID
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT [Base64] FROM NdviImageHistory X WHERE X.ID = nih_ID.MAX_ID
)nih
```

User more outer apply for all this tables {nih , ncih, nh, fsh }
and try this.

I am using only 1 outer for [nih]

Remove TOP 1 and Order by from OUTER APPLY Joins

Comment: Are you sure that this will compile?

Comment: Yes its working , if you can add more outer for every table i mention on solution.

Comment: OK, why do you think that this will perform faster than original query?